# Is it possible to fake a Python package's whl hash on PyPi?

Tags: python, security, hash, pip, pypi

I am thinking about how to ensure security when installing . If I install a package with pip I want to know that it is what I think it is.

One option might be to use a hash. I see that [`pip hash`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_hash/) provides a way of creating hashes for myself, however I also see that hashes can be found on PyPi.

Here is an example:

[image]

Is there a way that these online hashes can be faked? Or can I always trust that the hash is for the `whl`file I install from?